# Is there a way to call a script when Ubuntu wakes up from suspend or hibernate mode?

Tags: ubuntu, script, hibernate, suspend

I have a little shell script that I run automatically when I log on to my Ubuntu machine; it will set the parameters of my touchpad the way I like it. However, when Ubuntu wakes up after being hibernated or suspended, my touchpad reverts to its default state and I have to run my little script again.

Is there some way I can automate this process thus that the script will be magically called when the machine wakes up again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you have found a bug. The user is not supposed to bother with the touchpad configuration being lost after resume. You go to [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) and report this bug, so that it can be properly identified and fixed.

Then, after that, go to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` and add a script that will be executed before and after suspending or hibernating. The script receives a single command-line parameter "suspend", "resume", "hibernate" or "thaw", it should inspect this argument and take the appropriate action. There should be at least one other script in that directory (`99laptop-mode`) that you can use as a reference.

Comment: I did create the script and I made sure that it is being run. But it doesn't seem to have any effect. I guess this is due to that bug, though.

Comment: Perhaps, the touchpad is reinitialized after the resume scripts are run... losing its configuration.

Comment: Here's a complete example of the script: [ubutnuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1484156).

Comment: I'd like to add that this facilities are documented in `man pm-action` which, btw, says that the user supplied scripts should be named 00 - 49.