# Scripts under pm/sleep.d are not getting called when suspending with KDE 4.3

Tags: kde-4, suspend, slackware

Fujitsu-Siemens H240, Slackware-current, KDE 4.3.2.

I would like to perform some additional steps when my laptop suspends.

I found this SU [question](https://superuser.com/questions/60473/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-script-when-ubuntu-wakes-up-from-suspend-or-hibernate-mo) which is very close to what I am asking, however the scripts that I placed in that directory are not being called for me.

This could be a Slackware thing, or its possible that KDE has a different location for these scripts.

I am suspending by using the "Suspend" radio button on the "Guidance Power Manager" dialog of KDE.

Is there a standard location where I can place my scripts so they'll be run before and then after the machine has suspended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working on my system.  I'm pretty sure it was because I was using symbolic links.

I regularly backup my `/home`, but nothing else.  In order to catch the few scripts I've modified in `/etc` I use a directory off my home dir and I then add a symlink in the `/etc` location.

In this case, the script which walks through these directories is checking that the file exists and is a "regular file":

```
if [ -f "$syshooks/$base" ]; then
  hook="$syshooks/$base"
```

As a result, my scripts were not being considered at all.  By copying them directly into `/etc/pm/sleep.d` they are all called correctly.